# Determine max in array

Tags: c, arrays, max

I need something in my program to determine the max of array: printarr[]

The function of the code is to print *'s for the amount of numbers that are entered by the user.
Then the *'s have to be scaled by a factor of 30, so the number that has been entered most is represented by 30 *'s.

This is the code i have so far:

Can someone pls help me by finding a solution to determine the max of printarr[]

:)

```
#include <stdio.h>;

int main() {
int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };          
int i, j, n, x;
int one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, four = 0, five = 0, six = 0, seven = 0, eight = 0, nine = 0, ten = 0;

printf("Enter integers from 1 - 10\n");
printf("\nEnter -1 to finish input.\n\n");

for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x == -1) {                                      
        break;
    }

    if (x == numbers[0]) {
        one++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[1]) {
        two++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[2]) {
        three++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[3]) {
        four++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[4]) {
        five++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[5]) {
        six++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[6]) {
        seven++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[7]) {
        eight++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[8]) {
        nine++;
    }
    if (x == numbers[9]) {
        ten++;
    }
}

int printarr[] = { one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten };

for (n = 0; n <= 9; n++){
    printf("\n%d: ", n);
    for (j = 1; j <= /* 30/max * */ printarr[n]; j++)
        printf("*");
}

printf("\n\nPress enter to close program!");
fflush(stdin);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now, imagine if you had 1,000 numbers.  I don't think your solution would be feasible, unless you have great patience.

Comment: My first for-loop only accepts 100 numbers. 
But what your trying to say, is that the program will be terribly slow, of it wont work at all?

Comment: I'm not talking about the input loop.  I'm speaking of the code after the input loop.  What I'm saying is that you'll go nuts typing in over 1,000 lines of basically the same thing.  Since insanity shouldn't be an option when writing code, wouldn't you think there are more automated ways of accomplishing this?  Maybe loops and arrays?

Comment: Ah I know what you mean now, yeah I think there should be an easier (less time) way to do this. Instead of one++ , two++ and so on.

But I'm quit new to this, so I was happy with what I came up with. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the max of an array `v` of size `size` you can use something like this:

```
int find_max(int* v, size_t size) {
  int max=v[0];
  size_t i;
  for (i=0; i<size; ++i) {
    if (v[i] > max) max = v[i];
  }
  return max;
}
```

The precondition to this function is to have at least one element on the array. That's it, if the `v` array does not have any elements this function returns garbage.

Comment: Thanks really helpful!

I putted this function above the main function, then call in the for loop to " max ".

But that doesnt seem to work, am I doing something wrong?

This are the errors shown:

Warning 1 warning C4067: unexpected tokens following 
Warning 2 warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'max'

Comment: I've putted it in the main function, edited to my own integers/arrays and it works now! Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

I won't provide you a full solution, but I'll guide you through it.

In order to get the largest value, you should first pick the first element and pretend that it's the largest one. You save it in a variable called `max` for example.

Then you iterate on the array, when you find larger one, you assign it to `max`. After you iterate on the array, you'll get the largest number in `max`.

Example:

```
myArr = {3,1,6,2}
```

`max` is 3, then we iterate. Is 1 larger than 3? No.. Is 6 larger? Yes, we assign 6 to `max`. Is 2 larger than 6? No, we leave `max`. Final result: `max = 6`.

Comment: Exactly! But be careful from `i < 9`, since you're doing `i + 1` you might be out of bounds. It should be `i` instead.